# Script Execution with .load()

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form inside a DIV (normally the div is hidden using "display:none;")
The user open the DIV with: `onclick='$("#Details").show("slow");`
Fills out the form and save the data.

I don't want the entire page to be reloaded, and I need only this DIV to be reloaded

I tried:

```
function(data) {
    $('#Detalils').load(location.href + ' #Detalils');
});
```

and:

```
$("#Detalils").load(location.href + " #Detalils, script");
```

and:

```
$('#Detalils').load(location.href + ' #Detalils', function() {
$('#script').hide();
})
```

where in #script I put my script

In this div I have some script, and because of the jQuery on load script execution, the script is not executed.

I cannot put the script in an external file, it must be in the page body.

Is there a way to execute the script a well?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "reload the div" ? This can mean many different things.

Comment: remove() the div based on a condition, and re-call the function again that loads your load() request on a click event.

Comment: Use Ajax with GetScript, to load your external data and the js file that runs it.  Place GetScript in the callback function.

Comment: Also, make sure your loaded content is only the content you need, not a whole page....alot of beginners Ive seen try to just load a whole page...when they should be loading just the content needed

Comment: @Dany Caissy: it means that the user can use the form again (the form is in the DIV), but in the same time the data available in the forms select list is updated with the data already inserted

Comment: You can either empty the fields one by one, or delete the div and create a new one. What is your problem?

Comment: the only problem is that the script in the DIV cannot be used after reload, this came from the Script Execution when using .load() in iquery

Comment: @kylek: I'm loading only the content I need, this is why In ended up with this issue :) thx for the advice

Comment: @ blachawk: I don't want to put my script in external file: too many variables to pass

Comment: @blachawk: I think it might work, but could you give me an example? I can't quite get it in practice. keep in mind that the reload of the DIV must occur only when a condition is meet

Comment: Adding and removing Javascript code is not a good practice and it might never work. See my answer.

Comment: @bogdA, I got a demo setup below..

Answer (score 0):

Your actual Javascript code should not be within the div, that is the issue. If you wish to reload the form for the user to enter new data, then use ID's on the elements within your forms and write your JQuery code outside of it or in an external file, here is a simple example :

**Instead of something like  :**

```
<form>

    <input type="button" onclick="alert('hello');"> Click me ! </input>

</form>
```

**Do something like :**

```
<form>

    <input id="myButton" type="button"> Click me ! </input>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $("#myButton").click(function() 
    {
        alert('hello');
    });

</script>
```

You will have to adapt your code to this, of course, but you don't have another choice. HTML code can be removed and added at will, but Javascript code must not be treated the same way. There are many reasons for this, but one reason is that the browser will only load the Javascript functions once, for obvious optimization reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The works within my local environment.  Give it a shot in yours.

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="/" id="mremovebtn" title="remove">Remove</a>
<a href="/" id="mreloadbtn" title="reload">Reload</a>
<div id="Details">my details box</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mload() {
/*LOAD IN MY EXTERNAL STUFF*/
    mtarget =  $('#Details'); //the element on your page, that houses your external content
    mscript = 'external.js'; //the js script required for your plugin to work
    mtarget.load("external.html", function(){
    $.getScript(mscript, function() {
        //run the plug-in options code for your external script here
    });
 });
//*/
}

function madjustments() {
/*ADJUST THE LOADING PROCESS*/
    //remove the load request on click from your remove button
    $('#mremovebtn').on("click",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#Details').children().remove();
    });

    //reload the request on click from your reload button
    $('#mreloadbtn').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      mload();
    });
//*/
}


(function($){
  mload();
  madjustments();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

You will obviously need 2 additional files.  One called external.html and another called external.js, for my demo code to work. But you can change the naming process to whatever works for you.

Extra:
Set a class in your external html file (on the parent element), for example #external.  And by default, set the CSS to display:none in the style sheet.  Then when the page loads in, simply show() it in the jQuery code.